# How to access the HTTP request and response objects in METOR application iron router

Tags: http, meteor, iron-router

I am working on the meteor application ,which has iron router in application .I required to access http request and response object in router ,for accessing the request data.

Answer (score 0):

To access the `request` and `response` objects, all you need to do is tell Iron Router that this route is a server only route by passing an options object with `{ where: 'server' }` like so:

```
Router.route('/hello', function () {
  var req = this.request;
  var res = this.response;
  res.end('hello from the server\n');
}, { where: 'server' });
```

Or if you want to use different functions for different Methods:

```
Router.route('/hi', { where: 'server' })
  .get(function () {
    var req = this.request;
    var res = this.response;
    res.end('hello from the server\n');
  })
  .post(function () {
    var req = this.request;
    var res = this.response;
    doSomething(req.body)
    res.end('done\n');
  });
});
```

See more in the docs: http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/

Comment: I am using  Router.go('home_private.product', {productID:product }); at frontend. And at backend   this.route('home_private.product', {path: '/product/:productID',
      controller: productController
    }); 
then how to use  { where: 'server' } when using router.go() method?

Comment: I am doing like this but not working-
Router.route('/payment/:bidID', {
      where: 'server',
      name:'home_private.wtbPayment',
      controller: paymentController
    }
  ).post(function () {
    var req = this.request;
    var res = this.response;
    console.log(res);
  });